# simpler way to write if today or tomorrow is between ColA or ColB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE
getdate() between SPRFRDTE and SPRTODTE
or dateadd(DD, 1, getdate()) between SPRFRDTE and SPRTODTE
```

is there a way to write this as `if TODAY or TOMORROW is between SPRFRDTE and SPRTODTE` rather than `if TODAY is between SPRFRDTE and SPRTODTE or if TOMORROW is between SPRFRDTE and SPRTODTE`

Comment: Are the columns of type `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Comment: @ypercube they are `date` colums

Comment: So if today is `2015-12-11` and the 2 columns are `2015-12-01` and `2015-12-11`, the row should be returned, right?

Comment: yes correct. sorry i wasnt so detailed.

Comment: you probably shouldn't use `BETWEEN`, see [Aaron's article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is how to check for overlapping ranges:

```
WHERE SPRFRDTE <= dateadd(day, 1, cast(getdate() as date))
  AND cast(getdate() as date) <= SPRTODTE 
  AND SPRFRDTE <= SPRTODTE ;                 -- this might not be needed.
```

The very last condition is just a technical detail and may not be needed if you are sure (i.e. there is a constraint) that enforces that `CHECK (SPRFRDTE <= SPRTODTE)`.

If however such abnormal values are allowed, you need to include that condition as well for the query to be equivalent to the version with the two `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Saying if a date is today or tomorrow is effectively the same as allowing start date be one day earlier. So you can reword this as:

```
getdate() between SPRFRDTE-1 and SPRTODTE

getdate() value     |   Start date  |  End date |  result
---------------------------------------------------------------
today = tomorrow -1 |   tomorrow    |           | return row
today               |               |  today    | return row
```

Comment: This will also be true for today at noon, when `SPRFRDTE` is tomorrow's date. `getdate()` returns a datetime, not date.

Comment: @ypercube, Would not implicit conversion for `getdate` work here and make it `date`?

Comment: No, the implicit conversion will be from date->datetime in this case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5011